# Capillary waves in tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, floats, fillbetween

Here I am again humbly pleading for your assistance.
I need to replicate this figure:
[image]

So far, I have managed to get this (the view point is not so important):
[image]

But I am struggling to replicate the effect of the caterpillar waves on the top view.

I tried using the decoration library, with the snake shape, and fill between paths, but it is evident that the result is far from want I need.

Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,import,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{universalis}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\definecolor{maincolor}{cmyk}{1, .50, .10, .01}
\tikzstyle{Axes_s} = [color=black,thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{wborder} = [color=maincolor,thick, line join = bevel]

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{35}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
% Lenght of the cube
    \def\l{1}
% Points on the floor    
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);         % Centre
    \coordinate (A) at (-5*\l,0,0);     % Left
    \coordinate (B) at (0,5*\l,0);      % Right
    \coordinate (C) at (-5*\l,5*\l,0);  % Behind
% Points on the top    
    \coordinate (Oa) at ($(O)+(0,0,\l)$);   % Centre above
    \coordinate (Aa) at ($(A)+(0,0,\l)$);   % Left above
    \coordinate (Ba) at ($(B)+(0,0,\l)$);   % Right above
    \coordinate (Ca) at ($(C)+(0,0,\l)$);   % Behind above
% Axis
    % \begin{scope}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords]
    %   \draw[Axes_s] (O) -- (\l,0,0) node[below, pos=1.0]{$x$};
    %   \draw[Axes_s] (O) -- (0,7*\l,0) node[below, pos=1.05]{$y$} ;
    %   \draw[Axes_s] (O) -- (0,0,2*\l) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
    % \end{scope}
% Left face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \path[name path=leftfloor] (A)--(O);
    \path[wborder,name path=lefttop] (Aa)--(Oa);
    \tikzfillbetween[of=leftfloor and lefttop] {bottom color = maincolor!10, top color= maincolor!10}; 
    \draw[wborder] (Aa) -- (A) -- (O) -- (Oa);
    \draw[wborder, decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm, pre length=4pt, post length=4pt}] (Aa) -- (Oa);
    % Braces
    \coordinate (xw1) at ($(Aa)!0.15!(Oa)$);
    \coordinate (xd1) at ($(Aa)!0.7!(Oa)$);    
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1pt,aspect=0.5, mirror}] (xw1) -- (xd1) node[black,midway,xshift=0cm, yshift=-0.5cm, font=\footnotesize,align=center,transform shape] {Length of fetch};  
\end{scope}
% Right face
\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
    \path[name path=rightfloor] (B)--(O);
    \path[wborder,name path=righttop] (Ba)--(Oa);
    \tikzfillbetween[of=rightfloor and righttop] {bottom color = maincolor!10, top color= maincolor!10}; 
    \draw[wborder] (Ba) -- (B) -- (O) -- (Oa);
    \draw[wborder, decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm, pre length=4pt, post length=4pt}] (Ba) -- (Oa);
\end{scope}
% Braces on the right behind face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=5*\l]
    \coordinate (x1) at (-5*\l,\l);
    \coordinate (x2) at ($(-5*\l,\l)!0.33!(0,\l)$);
    \coordinate (x3) at ($(0,\l)!0.33!(-5*\l,\l)$);
    \coordinate (x4) at (0,\l);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.25}] (x1) -- (x2) node[black,midway,transform shape,xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=0.8cm, font=\footnotesize,align=center] {  Ripples to\\ wind waves};    
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.65}] (x2) -- (x3) node[black,midway,transform shape,xshift=0.3cm, yshift=0.8cm, font=\footnotesize,align=center] { Fully developed\\ seas};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,raise=2pt,aspect=0.5}] (x3) -- (x4) node[black,midway,transform shape,xshift=0.7cm, yshift=0.8cm, font=\footnotesize,align=center] { Swell waves};
\end{scope}
% Top face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\l]
    \draw[wborder, name path= righttop, decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm, pre length=4pt, post length=4pt}] (Ba) -- (Ca);
    \path[wborder, name path= righttop2, decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm, pre length=4pt, post length=4pt}] (Aa) -- (Oa);
    \draw[wborder, decorate, decoration={snake,segment length=1.64mm,amplitude=0.2mm, pre length=4pt, post length=4pt}] (Aa) -- (Ca);
    \tikzfillbetween[of=righttop and righttop2] {left color = maincolor!10, right color= maincolor!10, fill opacity=0.1};
\end{scope}    
% Arrows wind direction
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=2*\l]
    \coordinate (xw) at ($(Aa)!0.5!(Ca)$);
    \coordinate (xd) at ($(Oa)!0.5!(Ba)$);
    \coordinate (xw0) at ($(Aa)!0.2!(Ca)$);
    \coordinate (xd0) at ($(Oa)!0.2!(Ba)$);
    \node[draw,fill=green!20, single arrow,transform shape,font=\footnotesize,align=center] at ($(xd)!0.2!(xw)$) {Direction of\\wave propagation};
    \node[draw,fill=green!20, single arrow,transform shape, font=\footnotesize,align=center] at (xw) {Wind};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi.  Do you have at your disposal the equations describing the movement of the water surface (the waves)?

Comment: Hi @DanielN, no, that is the issue. I do not have the equations at hand.

Comment: Well then, it will be a piece of art.  You should construct the sections by hand (I think it will be quicker that way) and draw the transversal waves like a painter using the `shade` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I tried to work up a function `wave` that struggles to approach the drawing you were talking about.  I'm not very proud of the result, but maybe you can use it, or improve it...

**Some remarks**

1. The function is represented using `\addplot3` a color map.
2. The bottom part of the drawing is based on `fill between`.
3. The arrows are outside the `axis` environment and so the default coordinate system must have the z axis pointing upwards; I use the variable `\lattitude` *to stress the connection* between the two coordinate systems.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, math}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps, fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\xdefinecolor{brgb}{RGB}{0, 0, 189}
\xdefinecolor{trgb}{RGB}{105, 255, 255}

\tikzmath{%
  integer \sampls;
  \sampls = 75;
  real \lattitude, \H, \L, \arrowy;
  \lattitude = 70;
  \H = .3;
  \L = 2;
  \arrowy = 4*\L;  %% controls the y position of the two arrows
  function wave(\x, \y) {%
    \a = pow(\x, 2);
    \b = pow(.75*\y, 2);    
    \res = 1/2*pow(cos(360*sqrt(\a +\b)/(.7*\L)), 2);
    \res = \res +1/5*cos(360*2*\x/\L -\y*abs(\y));
    \res = \res +1/2*pow(cos(380*\L/\x), 2);
    return \H*(2 -\x/\L*\res);
  };
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    view={30}{\lattitude},
    height=4cm,
    width=10cm,
    scale only axis,
    zmin=-.8, zmax=.5,
    shader=flat,
    colormap={tmpwaves}{%
      rgb255=(0, 17, 204)
      rgb255=(0, 77, 255)
      rgb255=(105, 255, 255)
      rgb255=(215, 255, 255)
    },
    hide axis,
    % colorbar,
    % colorbar style={font=\scriptsize},
    scale=1.3]

    \addplot3[domain=0.2:{3*\L}, name path=xline,
    draw=none] (\x, -\L, -.8);
    \addplot3[domain y=-\L:{1.5*\L}, name path=yline,
    draw=none] (3*\L, \y, -.8);
    \addplot3[name path=xcurve,
    domain=0.2:{3*\L}, domain y=0:0, samples=\sampls,
    draw=none] (\x, -\L, {wave(\x, -\L)});
    \addplot3 [domain y=-\L:{1.5*\L}, name path=ycurve, draw=none]
    (3*\L, \y, {wave(3*\L, \y)});

    \addplot[top color=trgb, bottom color=brgb]
    fill between[of=xcurve and xline];
    \addplot[fill=brgb]
    fill between[of=yline and ycurve];

    \addplot3[surf, domain=0.2:{3*\L}, domain y=-\L:{1.5*\L},
    samples=\sampls] {wave(\x, \y)};
  \end{axis}

  %% the arrows
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{\lattitude}{30}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords, canvas is xy plane at z=5*\H,
    every node/.style={single arrow, transform shape,
      font=\normalsize, align=center}]
    \node[draw, orange!70!black,
    shade, left color=white, right color=orange,
    text width=8em, text height=3ex, text=black]
    at (-.3*\arrowy, \arrowy) {Wind};
    \node[draw, orange!70!black,
    shade, left color=white, right color=orange,
    text=black]
    at (3.8*\L, \arrowy -\L) {Direction of\\wave propagation};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this compile you exactly as it is? It doesn't work for me neither in Overleaf nor in Texstudio.

Comment: Hi @HIVP.  It works for me; the result of the compilation is `Output written on test_tikz.pdf (1 page, 172964 bytes).`  It takes some time though.  Do you have an error massage?